# Is there a way to make hg-git's push faster?

Tags: mercurial, hg-git

When using *hg-git* to push to a remote repository (using git+ssh://-protocol), it takes 10 minutes (and more) for one commit with a one-line change of a small file. The command I'm executing is:

```
hg push -B hg-experiments
```

Is there some more efficient command to push or is there some configuration of the local Mercurial or the remote Git repository which could help to make this faster? (What I've in mind here is e.g. the size of *packs* and the like.)

- Operating System: Windows 7
- Local Mercurial version: 2.2.1
- Remote Git version: 1.7.3.5
- hg-git version: changeset dfb2b7b5d586 from Sat May 12 03:33:19 2012 -0500

Comment: This isn't going to help you much, but as you might have wondered, no that is not the normal behavior. I don't know what about your setup is causing the trouble, but you shouldn't think that what you're seeing is inevitable.

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, I don't think there's anything that you can really do to improve the performance.

There are a couple outstanding performance issues in dulwich (the underlying Git library that Hg-Git users), that if fixed, might improve performance for you:

- [#562676 Push efficiency: MissingObjectFinder yields too many unnecessary objects](https://bugs.launchpad.net/dulwich/+bug/562676)
- [#562673 Push efficiency: objects in packs should be written as deltas](https://bugs.launchpad.net/dulwich/+bug/562673)

There's also some potential performance improvement work being done in Hg-Git itself:

- [Performance enhancements for exporting to Git](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/hg-git/1oZzvKABE08/discussion)